# Can you have a second "notes & attachment object" on an account?

Tags: attachment, account

We are currently loading PDF copies of invoices onto the account object as attachments, however these are being intermingled with other day to day attachments.

Does anyone have any advice as to how I could split these out?

Is it possible to create a second attachment object for the invoices, or would I need to look at adding a separate object (probably called invoices) and attaching the invoice to the relevant invoice object with a relationship lookup to the account.

Obviously depending on the solution I may need to add a new trigger to handle the lookup population.

Comment: Just a thought ,If you want to separate Invoices and it has some Identifier ,An inline Visualforce to show this should solve the problem ,Instead of creating more metadata just for this requirement

Comment: I'd store the invoice PDFs under Invoice and not Account, then maybe make do with some "View all invoices" custom link (leading to Report? VF page?). Other options might include Documents, Salesforce Content or Chatter library dedicated for invoice files (how sensitive is this data, everybody can view them?) or - purely for identifying purposes - you could enable Tags and start tagging your attachments... There also are storage usage considerations ;) I don't think this question has "right" answer...

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys, I've started looking into inline Visualforce and found a good piece of code for a "search box" of opportunity's which I thought would work as users would be looking for a specific invoice, however I haven't managed to adapt it yet.  I think I'll probably go with the option of adding them to an invoices object, although this would mean a related list before getting to the attachments which I personally am not that keen on in SF1. I'll update with the way I end up going.